# Find Code from Another Sheet and Return Info From Same Row

Tags: excel, vba

I have searched to find the answers to get to where I am but am now stuck! I am a relative beginner with VBA.

I have a Workbook that lists a few hundred orders that we are producing for our customer.

The order details are on the first sheet called "`In Progress`" and on the 3rd sheet called "`StyleData`" are more details about each product such as its composition, design reference, SKU etc...

At present my code searches column A on the Data sheet based on the 6 digit style code in the active cell on the In Progress Sheet, then goes to that cell. I have put a `MsgBox` in purely to put a pause in the code so I know where it has got to.

What I want it to do after finding the style code on the data sheet is return a value on the same row from column H, preferable in a format that the use can select and copy, then it will return to the original cell at the start of the macro.

Code as follows:

```
Sub get_composition()

Dim item_no As String
Dim data_sheet As Worksheet
Dim found_item As Range
Set Rng = ActiveCell

item_no = ActiveCell.Value
Set data_sheet = Sheets("StyleData")

If Trim(item_no) <> "" Then
    With Sheets("StyleData").Range("A:A")
        Set found_item = .Find(What:=item_no, _
                        After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                        LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False)
        If Not found_item Is Nothing Then
            Application.Goto found_item, True
        Else
            MsgBox "Nothing found"
        End If
    End With
End If

MsgBox "Return to Original Cell"

Application.Goto Rng

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

if I understand what you want :

you arrive at cell "found_item" and want to return a value from the same row.
If it's so, you can use method Offset on "found_item"

found_item.Offset() allow you to navigate from the current range
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840060.aspx

If you are on column A, found_item.Offset(, 1) will return the range on the same line but column B

Comment: Brilliant thanks, there might be more questions but we shall see when I next get stuck!